# creating a hyperlink from a form select value

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I would like to make a simple drop down menu when you click your choice from the list, it acts as a link.

Sorry for title being so ambiguous, I just do not have any idea what to call this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that when you select an option from a drop-down, the browser goes to a different URL?

If so, here's a good page that describes how to accomplish that: http://www.davesite.com/webstation/js/theory1jump.shtml

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a select list with attributes representing the links, then use JavaScript to jump to a link when it's clicked.

But a more accessible way would be to create a list of links, then use JavaScript to construct  a select list from them. This way, the links would still work if JavaScript was turned off.

With jQuery, something like:

```
<a href="http://example1.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com">Link 2</a>
```

And your script is:

```
var $sel = $("<select/>")
  .appendTo("body")
  .change(function() {
    document.location.href = $sel.val();
  })
$("a").each(function() {
  $("<option/>")
  .appendTo($sel)
  .val(this.href)
  .html(this.innerHTML)
});
```